# Need some advice regarding a media query and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I'm hoping someone is able to help with an issue I'm currently having with a website I am designing. The media query for mobile is where I'm getting hung up.

[This is an image of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKh4i.jpg)

The content isn't centered. I can fix the text simply with a text-align property, and I assume that I can just make the image display as a block and use margin: 0 auto to center it, the problem is that the container itself is not centered. I'm using Bootstrap, and it's all in a Bootstrap container.

I think part of the issue is that on small screens, I am hiding some content that is to the right of the content I can't get centered using Bootstrap's "hidden-xs" and "hidden-sm" properties.

Here is the code for the relevant section in the screenshot, plus my CSS for the media query. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

```css
/* Content Styles*/
.gas-content {
 margin: 4.50em 0 4.50em 5%;
}

.left-content {
 margin: 2.50em 0 2.50em 5%;
}

.content-container {
 width: 75%;
 float: left;
}

.test-container {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 margin-top: -10px;
}

.move-up {
 margin-top: -2em;
}

.move-down {
 margin-top: 2em;
}

.img-center {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-heading {
 color: rgb(3, 17, 85);
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 1.50em;
}

.services li {
 color: rgb(3, 17, 85);
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.emergency-services li {
 color: rgb(3, 17, 85);
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.contact-box {
 background-color: rgb(3, 17, 85);
 padding: 2em 0 6.50em 0;
}

.contact-box h3 {
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-left: 15px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.contact-info {
 color: white;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

.eztouselogo {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.services-left {
 margin-right: 0.50em;
}

.content-paragraph {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin-bottom: 5em;
 line-height: 2.25em;
}


@media (max-width: 991px) {
 .test-container {
  display: none;
 }

 .content-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
 }

 .container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
 }

 .pipes-img {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
 }
}
```

```html
    <!--Begin Main Content -->
   <div class="container"> <!--New Container -->

    <div class="content-container"> <!--Content on Left Side of Testimonials -->
      <div class="row gas-content"> <!--Gas, Water, & Sewer Line Row -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="pull-left img-responsive pipes-img" src="img/pipes.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 move-up">
          <h3 class="content-heading">Gas, Water, &amp; Sewer Line Inspection and Replacement in the Pittsburgh Area</h3>
          <p class="content-paragraph">Vivamus id ante molestie, vehicula justo nec, facilisis justo. Sed efficitur feugiat accumsan. Nunc vitae fermentum nulla. Aliquam imperdiet nunc felis, et malesuada ligula molestie eget. Proin sodales dictum semper. Proin nec sodales quam. Maecenas ac erat non mauris laoreet volutpat. Proin egestas enim ut magna sagittis vulputate. Aenean non odio lacus. Nam vehicula metus viverra quam laoreet, nec interdum orci porttitor. Etiam gravida velit sit amet commodo suscipit. Cras est erat, scelerisque quis velit non, luctus molestie ex.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              <ul class="services services-left">
                <li>Sewer Lines</li>
                <li>Gas Lines</li>
                <li>Water Lines</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <ul class="services services-right">
                <li>Sewer Inspections</li>
                <li>Water Heaters</li>
                <li>Full-Service Plumbing</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!--End Gas, Water, & Sewer Line Row -->
```

Comment: could it be that `col-xs-8` is tripping you up? Do you want that be `col-md-8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `col-xs-8` to `col-md-8` to match the same breakpoint as that on the image. Otherwise, the `div` wrapping the image will be 100%, but the sibling `div` will remain 2/3s width.

Comment: [That did shift things a bit, but now I get this.](http://imgur.com/a/iflJ9)

Maybe it has something to do with floats? I'm clearing the containers in the css, but I'm not sure what else could be causing this.

Comment: I'll spin up a code pen and see if I can simulate what you're working with. Standby.

Comment: Thank you. If you need to see more of my code, please let me know. I'm continuing to work on it myself tonight, and if I don't figure it out, tomorrow morning, as well. If I find out the answer I'll be sure to update here. 

Actually, here is what I'm working with that I'm hiding on smaller screens: 
`<div class="test-container testimonials hidden-sm hidden-xs"> <!--Testimonial Container -->
          <h3>Testimonials &amp; Reviews</h3> 
          <p tags and such> 
</div>`

I have the .test-container class set to display:none on the smaller media query.

Comment: http://codepen.io/CRHain88/pen/BWMGMp — This is what I'm seeing in codepen after changing it to `col-md-8`. Is this what you're looking for? If so, you may have other code interfering. Also, this is using bootstrap 3.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, yes. I'll have to look over my CSS again and see if there's something conflicting with that section. I have a feeling maybe I need to reset my padding or margins something, maybe something is pushing it without me noticing. I added the rest of my css for the content sections to the original post, I probably should have done that before but I thought I knew where the problem was occurring.

Comment: I got it, there was indeed an issue with my spacing elsewhere. I had to fix a few margins. Thank you for your help, Christian.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we (*web developer*) need to customize the *media query* of Bootstrap Framework. Bootstrap has built-in or default media query that fits to all devices such as :

1. Extra small devices **Phones** (<768px) 
   Class prefix : `.col-xs-`
2. Small devices **Tablets** (≥768px) 
   Class prefix : `.col-sm-`
3. Medium devices **Desktops** (≥992px) 
   Class prefix : `.col-md-`
4. Large devices **Desktops** (≥1200px) 
   Class prefix : `.col-lg-`

We just need to use it "cleverly" as it is.